# Where I config CNAME in VPS Server without Cpanel

Tags: linux, vps, cname-record

I'm a newbie in linux/server configurations and I'm trying to redirect all subdomains of specific domain to specific url:

*.domain.com -> domain.com/test

With Cpanel visual support and CNAME I got it, but in my VPS server without cpanel I don't find **WHERE** to do this.

This link explain what I need to do, but don't where I do. (http://www.zytrax.com/books/dns/ch8/cname.html)

Can someone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**You can't redirect a hostname to an URL with DNS (`CNAME` record) alone.**

There's plenty of things you need to know, but the correct path may be this (or something similar):

1. You need to find out whether your VPS is the master name server for your domain. **If it is:**
2. Lets assume you have BIND. Your file location can be found from `/etc/bind/named.conf` (or any other config file included there, like `named.conf.local`). There should be line

   ```
   zone "example.com" { type master; file "/etc/bind/db/example.com"; };
   ```
3. In the zone file found, you can start by adding `* IN CNAME example.com.`
   and updating serial in your `@ IN SOA` to be in format `YYYYMMDDNN` with current date and order number.
4. Reload the changed zone file by command `rndc reload`.
5. Add the redirect as `VirtualHost` on your Apache configuration (e.g. by adding new file in `/etc/apache2/sites-available/subdomains.example.com`):

   ```
   <VirtualHost *:80>
       ServerName subdomains.example.com
       ServerAlias *.example.com
       Redirect / http://example.com/test
   </VirtualHost>
   ```
6. Enable site with `a2ensite subdomains.example.com` and `service apache2 reload`.

Whether the steps are exactly these or not, there will be all corresponding phases.

Comment: Great answer! I did not have Bind yet. But I follow all steps and works like a charm! Thank you Esa Jokinen!!!!

Comment: So even the (educated) guesses turned out to be right, then! Glad I could be of help.