# ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED in some networks

Tags: vps, apache2

I configured an VPS server to accept access in any subdomain on my site:
test.domain.com.br
info.domain.com.br
123test.domain.com.br
...

It's worked with help in this question ([Where I config CNAME in VPS Server without Cpanel](https://serverfault.com/questions/841343/where-i-config-cname-in-vps-server-without-cpanel/841353)).

My new problem is some networks don't load some pages. In my house works perfectly all pages, but in my job don't work. My friend's job works all pages, but in owner site don't.

The return error is ERR_NAME_NOT_RESOLVED.

I tried flush dns cache, make changes in VPS configs and some others.

Can someone give an idea?

Comment: Where is this error being raised? In the browser? An intermediate cache? This appears to be a DNS issue - so why are you talking oabout your VPS?

Comment: It happens in browser access. I quoted VPS because I set it myself, so since I'm a newbie, I may have been wrong enough somewhere.